# typescript react-router-dom useParams error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

interface IParams {
    id: string;
}

export const MyRestaurant = () => {
    const { id } = useParams<IParams>();
    return <h1>My Restaurant</h1>;
}
```

This throws an error when I try to get `params`. The error is:

```
Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Use bold face font to highlight only the most important bit. If everything is bold, nothing is important.

Comment: The code that you have posted here is correct.  @evelynhathaway is right that it's something with your environment, like perhaps your packages are using outdated versions.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript doesn't have types for `useParams`. This can be because you don't have the types or the types aren't up-to-date.

Try installing the latest version of the types package for React Router DOM.

```sh
npm install --save @types/react-router-dom@latest
```

I can confirm your code works using `react-router-dom@5.2.0` and `@types/react-router-dom@5.1.7`.